# asset pipeline image subfolders?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

My image assets setup is as follows:

```
assets/images/websites
```

then in the websites folder all of my images are housed.

When I use the scss helper: `image-url("menu-bg.png")` or `image-url("/websites/menu-bg.png")` it does not load the image whatsoever.

However, If the image is in the `/images` parent folder instead of the `/websites` subfolder and I use `image-url("menu-bg.png")` it will work perfectly.

How do I call an image from a subfolder?

Comment: Don't use a leading slash: `image-url("websites/menu-bg.png")`

Answer (score 3):

Quite likely the sub-folder is not part of the asset pipeline. Sub-folders are to be included in the asset pipeline with the following explicit configuration in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "images", "websites")
```

Comment: Would it be more appropriate to put it in `config/initializers/assets.rb` or no?